# BeanIO unquotedQuotesAllowed in CSV not working

Tags: java, csv, bean-io

I want parse file with delimeter. I use BeanIO 2.1.0. I have file, which contains a string in which there is a double quote:

```
"TEST"/37326330|TEST2
```

In config I set parameter:

```
<stream name="csvStream" format="csv">
     <parser>
         <property name="delimiter" value="|"/>
         <property name="unquotedQuotesAllowed" value="true"/>
     </parser>
</stream>
```

But it not working! I get error:

```
org.beanio.MalformedRecordException: Malformed record at line 1: Invalid character found outside of quoted field at line 1
```

But why? Why this parameter not working?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to preserve the double quotes (`"`) in the parsed text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you want to preserve/retain the double quotes (`"`).

The `unquotedQuotesAllowed` config option is only applicable to CSV streams, but based on your sample test data, you are using a pipe symbol (`|`) as a delimiter. Yes, you can change the delimiter for a CSV stream, but I think it would be better to just use a stream mapping configured as a `delimited` format. IMO this is easier to work with and you don't need to comply to all the rules and subtleties of a CSV format.

I would then use the following:

```
<stream name="csvStream" format="delimited">
  <parser>
    <property name="delimiter" value="|"/>
  </parser>
  <record name="...">
  ....
  </record>
</stream>
```

Using the above mapping, I get the following output:

```
Field1: "TEST"/37326330, Field2: TEST2
```

Comment: Yes, it worked for me! But why it does not work for csv? After all, csv is the delimited file

Comment: I'm guessing it is because your delimiter is not a comma, but I might be wrong